# Appium Maven tests with Travis CI tool

Tags: java, maven, travis-ci

I am kind of struggling with transitioning from Jenkins to Travis-CI. Running an Appium (or consider it Selenium) project that is built using Maven. I am not sure what really should go into the `travis.yml` file. From what I have been told I need to do a `before_install`, `before_script`, and `script`, and `after` (after not sure). Could someone please be nice of kind enough to paste a travis.yml that was created for Java Maven project.

Also not sure I will get the test running on a physical device for a tool that is hosted on the Cloud. For Jenkins all we would do is hook up the device to the master/slave.

Comment: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/java#Projects-Using-Maven

Comment: yeah that is very minimal information..doesn't help much